# Java ArrayList call extended object function

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, extends

I have a `ArrayList<A>` and am putting "B" objects into it. In the code for "B" I am overriding the `print` function. However, in my code I end up getting the `print` function defined in "A" instead.

I was wondering if there was a way to get the "B" print function without using a if statement checking if "A" is a "instanceof" "B", if true then casting "A" to "B", then calling print. Let's also say I can't make the class abstract and can't make print abstract.

Here is my code to show what I mean:

Class A

```
public class A {

    public String print() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}
```

Class B

```
public class B extends A {

    public String print() {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}
```

Main:

```
ArrayList<A> objects = new ArrayList();
objects.add(new B());

Class a = objects.get(0);
a.print();
```

Output = "A"

So this will print "A". Again, I know I can use a if statement check if it's from the "B" class then cast type to object to it. But let's say I am going to put the whole alphabet into it and I don't want an if and a bunch of else if statements? Is that the only way?

Comment: Firstly your syntax is wrong, this wont compile because your method signatures tell the compiler that they will return a `String` however the methods do not return a `String` they are `void`

Comment: Also it should be `A a=objects.get(0);` and fixing these errors does in fact print "B"

Comment: This doesn't compile, so I doubt you've tested it. Assuming you change it to working code, then the function called will be the actual type. So if it's a B in a list of A's, it will still call the B method.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.

```
public class testing{
    private static class A{
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
    private static class B extends A{
        @Override
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<A> objects = new ArrayList<A>();
        objects.add(new B());
        A a = objects.get(0);
        a.print();    
    }
}
```

upon looking at your code, the print functions should return `void` not `String`, or better yet they should actually return a String instead of printing within the method (wither way this fixes compile errors).

You are missing the type argument when your create your `objects` ArrayList (seem my example).

Its better practice to add the `@Override` annotation to tell the compiler that you are in fact overriding a method (see example)

Lastly you cannot declare an instance of `A` the way you have (`Class a = objects.get(0);`) you need to actually declare it as type `A` or `B` (again see my example)